# How to make hover on table cells with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hover

I have my table with hover function on Rows, I am trying to change it to be hover on cells instead

**Here's my current script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
    var tfrow = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows.length;
    var tbRow=[];
    for (var i=1;i<tfrow;i++) {
        tbRow[i]=document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i];
        tbRow[i].onmouseover = function(){
          this.style.backgroundColor = '#f3f8aa';
        };
        tbRow[i].onmouseout = function() {
          this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

**And here what i tried to change so far but still not working:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
    var tfcell = document.getElementById('tfhover').cells.length;
    var tbCell=[];
    for (var i=1;i<tfcell;i++) {
        tbCell[i]=document.getElementById('tfhover').cells[i];
        tbCell[i].onmouseover = function(){
          this.style.backgroundColor = '#f3f8aa';
        };
        tbCell[i].onmouseout = function() {
          this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

**How can i achieve hover on cell instead of hover on row with my script?**

Comment: if you want jQuery, how about $("td").hover()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular CSS for this purpose:

```
#tfhover td {
    background-color: #fff;
}
#tfhover td:hover {
    background-color: #f3f8aa;
}
```

Thanks to @Mike Brant for pointing out the missing table id

Comment: A very good alternate solution, though I think in his case the CSS selectors would be `#tfhover td` and `#tfhover td:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question... which is how to do this with jQuery:

```
$('#tfhover td').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fsf8aa');
}, function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
});
```

Of course your example has nothing to do with jQuery. It just reminds how much simpler these things become using jQuery.

Comment: can you check this please [Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/SsgeJ/) because your code making highlight instead of hover, or correct me.

Comment: @Leo Your example does not have jQuery at all, and I see you have updated your question to not include jQuery anymore.  If not using jQuery I would go with CSS option.

Answer (score 0):

Cells are in the list of row, as rows are in the list of table.

To get a cell, just **document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i].cells[j]** .Both lists start from 0.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
    var tfrow = document.getElementById('tfhover').rows.length;
    var tbRow=[];
    for (var i=1;i<tfrow;i++) {
        tbRow[i]=document.getElementById('tfhover').rows[i];
        var tfcell=tbRow[i].cells.length;
        for(var j=0;j<tfcell;j++){
            var _tbCell=tbRow[i].cells[j];
            _tbCell.onmouseover=function(){
                this.style.backgroundColor = '#f3f8aa';
            }
            _tbCell.onmouseout=function(){
                this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>
```